# What is the reason/origin of textwidth=78 (rather than 80)?

Tags: vim

In vim, it seems common practice to set the textwidth to 78 and not (as I'd expect) 80 characters. I see this everywhere (help pages, modelines, vimrcs, etc).

Just curious, does anyone know why this is?

Edit: I understand the origin/reasoning for setting a textwidth of 80 characters. Just curious why it's common practice to set the width 2 characters less than 80.

Comment: Terminal screens were 80 characters wide but I would say it makes some sense to stop a little bit before the limit.

Comment: RFC2822 (email) also as 78 characters; perhaps it's related to this... Not sure why (the RFC mentions "to accomodate all user interfaces...")

Comment: I would expect 1 character border (east/west , north/south) and the rest is the active real estate. text on the borders (especially with old CTR based monitors) got warped on the edges under some circumstances.

Comment: IBM/Hollerith punched cards were 80 columns wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, [RFC2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) (Internet Message Format, or "email") recommends a line length of 78 (excluding CRLF). The rationale it gives is

> The more conservative 78 character recommendation is to accommodate the many implementations of user interfaces that display these messages which may truncate, or disastrously wrap, the display of more than 78 characters per line

I don't think RFC2822 is *why* you see 78-character line lengths so commonly, but I suspect the justification is similar. In the ages of yore, terminals were typically 80-column display devices. A text line length of 78 left you with two columns worth of "UI" space to display things like buffer scroll position, or line numbers.

100 lines is enough for anybody, right?